# Losing all test coverage when testing individual class

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I am writing tests for my apex classes. Usually I can test each test class individually from the developer console.

[image]

When I run the idividual test my code coverage is 0% even if the class passed.

My only option is to go through Setup|Apex Classes|Run All Tests
[image]

When I edit the test class I lose all my test coverage.

Is there anyway I can set it up so I can test each class individually without losing my entire test coverage and not have to navigate to the Run All Tests?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not storing individual test coverage.

Go to Apex test execution, click options button, make sure you have unchecked store aggregate test coverage.

[image: Apex Test execution]