# Test class not covering Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I am setting a field using based on one other field value using Trigger when new record is created or existing record updated. The trigger works fine. I have written a Test class for the Trigger but somehow, it doesn't cover a single line of the Trigger. I have gone through almost all topics here but nothing seems to work.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger SMS_OPT_OUT on Account (before insert, before update) {
for (Account A : Trigger.new) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        A.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = A.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail;
    } else if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        Account oldA = Trigger.oldMap.get(A.Id);
        if (A.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c != oldA.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c || A.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail != oldA.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail) {
            if (A.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c == oldA.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c && A.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail != oldA.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail) {
                A.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = A.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class SMS_OPT_OUT_TC{
    static testmethod void triggerTest(){
        RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'];
        User thisUser = [ select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
        System.runAs ( thisUser ) {
            Account a = NEW Account();
            a.FirstName='John';
            a.LastName='DoeTest1';
            a.PersonEmail = 'doetest1@test.com';
            a.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = false;
            a.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = true;
            a.RecordType = personAccountRecordType;
            insert a;
            a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id =:a.Id];
            a.PersonHasOptedOutOfSms__c = false;
            update a;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: Just curious...I could be wrong here...after inserting "a"...have you tried querying the record back and set the "personhasoptedoutofsms__c" field ?

Comment: `PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail` is a Person Account field. You might try modifying your insert to include the recordtype for the Person Account type on it and see if the behavior changes. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/29833/660

Comment: This might sound stupid but have you executed your test class? By clicking run test? If yes, is there any error you receive while inserting Account? Does the test passed

Comment: @ZenSeeker: yes, I tried that as well. Didn't worked.

Comment: @MarkPond: I tried that approach. Not working.

Comment: @manjit_singh: yes, I run test. It completes successfully. Debug log also displays proper value when I tried. But code coverage for Triggers still says 0%

Updated my code as per suggestions.

Comment: @Neerav can you check two things. `1` Is the aggregate code coverage turned off? [Aggregate Coverage](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92961/losing-all-test-coverage-when-testing-individual-class/93021#93021)
. Store only aggregate coverage should be unchecked. `2. ` Does the debug log shows that your trigger is invoked while executing test class? can you post your debug log here?

Comment: Thank you very much for the 1st step guidance @manjit_singh. It was unchecked already and didn't help me directly but indirectly it fixed my issue. When I run the Test on 'Apex Test Execution' page, it works. Weird that its not working when I run test from Developer consol. Any idea why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but when I run test on 'Apex Test Execution' page, it works and covers Trigger code. Weird that its not working when I run test from Developer console. Anyway, I am happy that I can finally deploy it. Thanks @manjit_singh for your valuable direction.